# Cancel "Domain validation" for Front Door domain

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I was playing with Front Door and did set up a custom domain.
This domain is a Subdomain-delegations to my Azure subscription. Meaning for the domain `myCompany.com` I do not have access to the DNS settings, but the admin of myCompany set a delegation of `sub.myCompany.com` to a DNS zone in my Azure subscription. So I have a zone `sub.myCompany.com` in my account. Meaning I can only create A/Alias for `sub.myCompany.com` which I set to be an alias of my front-door.
This did work fine and I added the subdomain to my front-door and everything worked fine including using a SSL certificate from my KeyVault.
During playing around I tried using managed certificates and enabled that on the subdomain. And now the domain is stuck at "Domain validation" since a few days:
[image: Stuck state]

And I can't change this back because this results in the following error:

> Failed to update the custom https configuration
> Failed to update the custom https configuration for the frontend host '...'. Error: The requested operation cannot be executed on the entity in the current state.

**How can I cancel that state to set it back to my KeyVault certificate?**

I guess as this is not a CNAME-mapping it did fall back to e-mail verification and as the TLD is not under my control the mail got lost at the company managing the TLD. I do not have a direct contact with that company as I'm a subcontractor to the TLD's company and that company is also not managing the main domain on their own so it is not that easy to get ahold of whomever could have received that mail. And as the KeyVault certificate was working fine I just want to switch back to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the problem that the domain validation was still not completed after many days.

I then opened a ticket in Azure and then the process was terminated in the backend. After that I was able to start the domain validation again and then it worked within 1 hour with the certificate

Comment: My problem is I do not have a support contract and can't create technical tickets. BUT I already wrote the Azure Support via Twitter and they sent it forward and they are working on it...

Comment: Oh that's stupid.

I hope as a company the $29/month for Azure Support is affordable.
The possibility to open tickets will then be used more often. Especially if you use many services in Azure.

I hope Azure Twitter Support can help you.
But it also took me 4 days until the support reset the validation

Comment: It is only a "side-business" of mine and I try to avoid costs if not needed and so far I never needed a ticket which would require the paid support. And twitter support already gave me a one-time ticket to create a request. According to them the validation is already canceled with DigiCert, but it's not showing in their backend yet...

Comment: ...and its fixed now